# Java Iterate through a collection of classes and using their functions

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, iterator, loops

i wanted to know how i can iterate through a collection of classes and be able to use the classes functions on every pass.

Im new to java and im much more familier with c++.

This is the collection i wish to iterate..

```
private ArrayList<Album> albumCollection;
```

and activate the following function

```
 get title
```

This is my current code...

```
//Lists all stored titles
private void ListAllTitles(){
    int size = albumCollection.size();
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.println(albumCollection(i).getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to access an element from a `List`, you need to use the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method:

```
System.out.println(albumCollection.get(i).getTitle());
```

Also note, you could use the [for each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop to achieve this:

```
for (Album album : albumCollection) {
    System.out.println(album.getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This for each construct is simpler:

```
for (Album album : albumCollection)
{
     System.out.println(album.getTitle());
}
```